# like and nvl in jpql query - springboot JPA

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

i am trying to write the below query into spring boot jpql (postgresql db)

```
    first_name
FROM
    employees
WHERE
    first_name LIKE concat(concat('%',nvl(:key,first_name) ),'%'); --This is oracle style query
```

Iam trying to write the same  logic in JPQL(am new to JPA and JPL , but i know this simple logic ,we can achieve using the implementation less queires , but the above mentioned is a part of a bigger query).

I tried like below. But stuck actually.

```
 @Query("select pe.packageName from  PackageEntity pe where " +
            "lower(pe.packageName) like  " +
            "case when :packageName is null then lower(pe.packageName) else concat('%',lower(:packageName),'%') end " )
    List<String> getValues( @Param("packageName") String roomIDList);
```

Error Message is below

`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function lower(bytea) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 190`

Honestly , i've tried every possible solution , i can think of. found same error in stackoverflow , but there solution doesn't match, I really want to send the null values in the query , if the input is null then need to ignore the validation, for example if the input parameter is null, then i want to completely ignore the validation.

Comment: is your packageName field of String?
the error message says function lower(bytea)  not found. 

@Query("select u.name from  User u where lower(u.name) like  (case when :name is null then lower(u.name) else concat('%',lower(:name),'%') end)")

The above example perfectly works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution :-

```
@Query("select pe.packageName from  PackageEntity pe where " +           
            ":packageName is null or lower(pe.packageName) like 
              concat('%',lower(:packageName),'%')" )
```

The above workaround worked actually.

But I implemented like, In cotroller code

```
if (search.getPackageName() == null) {
            LOGGGER.info("Input Name is NULL");
            search.setPackageName("==!@#$%^&*()!@#$%^&*()==");
            LOGGGER.info("Input Name is set to Default " + search.getPackageName());
        }

 searchValue = repoPackage.getPackageAll(search.getPackageName());
```

in repo, where condition is like below - Not sure , if the solution is the best, but it worked. Like this I avoided sending any `null` value to `jpa`.

```
where
 (('==!@#$%^&*()!@#$%^&*()==' = :packageName) 
  or lower(pd.package_name) like concat('%', lower(:packageName), '%'))
```